# Написал код на TELLO EDU что бы можно было управлять и получать видео, но при взлёте видео застывает и ничего не показывает но управление остаётся

Tags: python, opencv

```
    import cv2
    from djitellopy import Tello
    import threading
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
    
    
    tello = Tello()
    
    tello.connect()
    
    tello.streamon()
    
    pygame.init()
    
    WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
    WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
    WINDOW_SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))
    
    def control_tello():
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    
                    if event.key == K_z:
                        tello.takeoff()
    
                    elif event.key == K_w:
                        tello.move_forward(30)
                    elif event.key == K_s:
                        tello.move_back(30)
    
                    elif event.key == K_a:
                        tello.move_left(30)
    
                    elif event.key == K_d:
                        tello.move_right(30)
    
                    elif event.key == K_r:
                        tello.move_up(30)
    
                    elif event.key == K_f:
                        tello.move_down(30)
       
                    elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                        tello.rotate_clockwise(30)
    
                    elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                        tello.rotate_counter_clockwise(30) 
    
                elif event.type == KEYUP:
                    if event.key in [K_w, K_s, K_a, K_d, K_r, K_f, K_RIGHT, K_LEFT]:
                        tello.send_rc_control(0, 0, 0, 0)
    
    control_thread = threading.Thread(target=control_tello)
    control_thread.start()
    
    def update_frame():
        global current_frame
        while True:
            frame = tello.get_frame_read().frame
            current_frame = frame
    
    update_thread = threading.Thread(target=update_frame)
    update_thread.start()
    
    
    while True:
        if current_frame is not None:
            frame = current_frame.copy()
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            pygame_surface = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame.swapaxes(0, 1))
            WINDOW_SURFACE.blit(pygame_surface, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()
    
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                break
    
    tello.land()
    
    pygame.quit()
    tello.streamoff()
    tello.end()
```

короче, я написал код он работает, но в чём проблема, в этом коде есть и управление дроном и получение кадр с дрона но когда дрон взлетает кадр застывает но управление всё ещё остаётся, я всё перепробовал поставил всё на первый поток, потом управление и получения кадра в раздельные потоки что бы не застывало, но всё равно показывает только кадр перед взлётом дрона